# Windows 8.1: WinJS: appbar won't open/show by default?

Tags: winjs, windows-8.1

I'm working on a Windows 8.1 app and on a data input page I would like the appBar to be open or visible by default as it contains the option to save the data.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br229676.aspx

I've looked at the link above and tried the show method in the following way:

Markup:

```
<div id="appbarCommands" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.AppBar" data-win-options="{sticky: 'true'}">
    <button data-win-control="WinJS.UI.AppBarCommand"
            data-win-options="{id:'cmdSaveCustomer', icon:'save', section:'global'}"
            data-win-res="{winControl: {label:'CRM_contactHistory_appBar_SaveLabel', tooltip:'CRM_contactHisory_appBar_SaveToolTip'}}"></button>
</div>
```

JS Code:

```
(function () {
        "use strict";

    WinJS.UI.Pages.define("/pages/CRM/customerDetails/contacts/contactHistory/contactHistory.html", {

        ready: function (element, options) {

            WinJS.UI.processAll().done(function () {

                setAppBarState(document.getElementById("appbarCommands"));

            });
            WinJS.Resources.processAll()            
        }
    });
})();

function setAppBarState(appBar) {

    appBar.winControl.show();

}
```

For whatever reason, the appBar doesn't launch. I've tested it in the appBar sample code and it works fine on there, but it doesn't work in the actual solution.

I wondered if someone could perhaps shed some light on the problem? Or perhaps knows of a reason that would prevent the appbar being shown when the page loads?

Many thanks

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through a lot of messing around and changing of values, I've got it working. It turns out that all appBars need to have Unique ID's regardless of the page they are on otherwise the properties of one are inherited from others on previous pages.

I've gone through the app and namespaced the ID's based on the page name and all the appBars now work as they should!

What a palava!

Comment: That's interesting, and points out why we general have global app bars and then show/hide commands based on the current page. You're saying, then, that you're defining separate app bars with each page control HTML? I would have expected those app bars to drop from the DOM. Something I'll have to check out.

Comment: So I tried this using the Nav App project template with two pages, each of this declared its own app bar with the same id. I didn't see any collision--the first page's sticky app bar worked fine, the second page's wasn't sticky, and going back to the first page I got the sticky behavior again. So I'm curious as to where you're defining the app bars. The behavior your describe suggests that the app bars aren't being unloaded with page navs, as I'm seeing.

Comment: Yes I was defining an appbar on each page, to be honest I hadn't thought about doing it globally but that does make more sense. Thanks again for the help and I look forward to the book being finished!

Answer (score 1):

Add the sticky property in your data-win-options in the HTML:

```
data-win-options="{ sticky: true }"
```

Then using show() should work just fine. I tested this in the HTML Appbar control sample and it worked.

Also, you don't need to call WinJS.UI.processAll within the ready method--processAll is called automatically when a page control is loaded. (The same is not true for WinJS.Resources.processAll, just UI.processAll.)

Comment: Hi Kraig! Thanks for the response. I do have the sticky property in the data-win-options but it still doesn't work. I've amended my example to include the mark-up I'm using as well in case there is something wrong with that. Has the final version of your book been released yet?

Comment: I see you found your problem below...I'll comment there. With the book, final book will be out in a couple months. The preview on http://aka.ms/BrockschmidtBook2 is pretty near final material for those chapters.